# Website reacts perfectly when testing responsiveness in developer tools, but isn't centered to screen on actual phone?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile, responsive-design

So I have a website that looks great when testing for responsiveness in developer tools, but isn't centered and looks somewhat broken when actually testing it on the iPhone itself.

What would cause this, and how can I fix it if I don't have access to an iPhone (looks fine on my android)?

[See site here](http://espritduvin.ca/)

Comment: Can this be caused by the fact that there is horizontal scroll when seen on a phone screen?

Answer (score 0):

The padding in this rule is the culprit, when you get rid of it you will see the difference:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px)
.tg-column-1, .tg-column-2, .tg-column-3, .tg-column-4 {
    float: none;
    padding-left: 34%;
}
```

To center the elements of `text-widget` you can try this instead of the padding you were using:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px)
   .textwidget div { margin: 0 auto; }
}
```

Comment: This actually fixed a problem I'd given up on before (centering that div) so thank you!

However the mobile problem remains :(

Comment: Possible to post a screenshot of how it looks in mobile?

Comment: I have been using http://mobilito.net/ to capture the shots, which leaves it somewhat hidden by the age verification window, but still shows the bottom half of the page snug up against the left window.

That is what is making this much more difficult, I don't have an iPhone on hand :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `overflow-x:hidden` in body in css mediaquery for mobile. There is horizontal scroll in the website in mobile view, it may be the cause of your problem.